# Make div so that you can press through it

Tags: html, css

How can I make my div so that you could click and hover over another div under it?

Comment: What have *you* attempted thus far? Or do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: Andrew L. I've tried anything I could imagine, and I have tried to google it around but don't know what to do.. Any help is respected :)

Comment: We have no idea what your imagination is capable of, so please state those tries in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pointer-events: none;` in the CSS of the overlaying div.

```css
div { position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px; top: 0; left: 0; transition: background-color .8s; }
div#first:hover { background-color: #f00; }
div#second { pointer-events: none; background-color: #00f; opacity: .2; }
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: This workes perfectly. Thank you!